# Download YouTube files using Mathematica

Tags: web-access

I am not that familiar with other languages, but I know Mathematica is powerful enough to excess webpage data (youtube copyright free database). I want to download sound effects from YouTube, but I feel frustrated that I have to do it one by one.

https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/soundeffects

Can I get a access the website by Mathematica and download the files (maybe all of it?)

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are many topics about web scraping and once you obtain urls you can download it using `URLDownload`.

Comment: I assume Google is smart enough to not expose those links directly. If so, there are likely two ways to do this easiest. 1) Write a scraper built off of the web-browser drivers that are in [`ExternalEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/WebDriverChrome.html)  2) Use the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

Comment: If you really want this I can write you a YouTube API connection, too. I'd just maybe need to find a day when I have some free hours here or there.

Comment: @b3m2a1  If you only show me how to start, that will be amazing. I only used mathematica for the modeling the physical/mathematical model, and does not have any knowledge of the web-coding. It would be really helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Kuba I was going over other people's question and try to understand how to do it, but I was having difficulty because I never work with with web-coding. However, Thank you for prividing some keyword to start!

Comment: Maybe you could try youtube-dl and you-get in python.

Comment: @b3m2a1 My understanding is that `ExternalEvaluate` can not be used for web scraping. There is a method to get the text of an element, but I don't see any way of retrieving HTML code and attributes.

Comment: @C.E. Can’t it run a Web Driver much like Arnoud’s web browser driver thing?

Comment: @b3m2a1 The problem is that you can navigate to different pages, click on things, take pretty pictures of the result etc. but you cannot retrieve the HTML of the website, even though the driver API supports this. It is an extremely stupid omission (if I'm right) because it makes it useless for anything other than taking pictures, but as I understand it this is how they made it.

Comment: @SaesunKim I finally bit the bullet and [built it](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer/serviceconnectionyoutube.html) but I'm not sure the YouTube API ever provides download links.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Sorry, I thought my question is forgotten. Thank you for follow up. For the looking at the download, I am not sure what I need to do. Anyway Can you answer the question instead of the comment? so I can accept your solution to be answer. I am sorry for late reply, and thank you so much for your time spending!